# What is the limit of $\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 4 \\ y \rightarrow \pi}} x^2 sin \frac{y}{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

$\displaystyle \lim_{\substack{x \rightarrow 4 \\ y \rightarrow \pi}} x^2 sin \frac{y}{x}$

I don't know in which way should I try to solve this example, can maybe the single variable limit of $sin \frac{1}{x}$ help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure about, that this limit exists

Comment: Did you mean $x\to 0?$ If not, plug it in. The function is continuous at $(4,\pi)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim _{ { x\rightarrow 4\\ y\rightarrow \pi  } } x^{ 2 }sin\frac { y }{ x } =16\sin { \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  } =16\frac { \sqrt { 2 }  }{ 2 } =8\sqrt { 2 } $$

Answer (score 3):

Your limit is simply

$$(4)^2\sin (\frac {\pi}{4} )$$
$$=8\sqrt {2} .$$